What are the options for moving a non-loadbearing wall in kitchen?


Does anyone have any experience removing a non-load bearing wall in a kitchen/living room similar to the one in the attached pictures? Wondering if this this a nightmare project, or a doable DIY.

This needs pictures or diagrams. Also note that asking for "ideas" is soliciting opinion, which leans into off-topic territory. Take the [tour] to find out how to keep your questions on-topic and get useful Answers.

Costs are also off topic.  If it is a non load bearing wall, then it is in DIY area, which can reduce costs.  Most of the costs are in the finishing.

Added a picture that hopefully helps. Sorry for the mixed questions, really just wondering if this is a project worth taking on or not.

Only you can determine if it's worth it to you or not. If you're interested in the change in market value of the house, talk with a local realtor who knows your local market. We don't have a clue where in the world you live, so we can't make guesses at that.

It isn't that big of a deal.
#1 - you can just cut the wall to cabinet height    If no sink there you can cut down to cabinet level and even do bar seating out to living room.    If sink then you just raise the bar - 6-8" over sink.   You don't even have to cut the bottom drywall and the only thing you may move on this side of the wall is the light switch down a few inches.
#2 - you can put in an island here or close to where wall is.   You need the outlet for the island and can route all of the electric under the cabinet footings.   The light switch could go on the island - not traditional but not overly weird.
#3 - you just get rid of the wall.   Also not hard at all.   Outlet probably not needed and light switch (outlet if you need) would go by that little lamp.
The hard part of this isn't the wall it is reconfiguring flooring and everything else on the other side of the wall.    If there is any duct work you can just cut it and have a floor register.   You electric is on the simple side to deal with too.
If you want to stay on the "really easy" side I would say option 1 can be done in a couple of days without a ton of skill needed (given you have someone install countertops).

Thank you DMoore for the insight, this is just the type of knowledge I was looking for!
